# How can one automatically "post" messages/E-Mails into teams channels? Is there a useable API?

Tags: python, microsoft-teams

I am currently developing a tool for my school's cafe (in which I work), which essentially uses a Python-based Web-App (I used streamlit for this) to track the inventory of our cafe. If a certain threshold is passed, the tool is currently utilizing google's Mail API to send an E-Mail to a certain set of addresses, in order to alert the ones buying the goods of the shortage.

As we use MS Teams for organization, it would be a valuable addition to utilize Teams in order to message the according persons quickly and efficiently.
Now, as I have never looked into the topic of MS Teams development, I was hoping that there is some tips/Ideas here.
I have previously developed a Discord Bot as a little project, so I do have some experience in that field.

The message is basically supposed to be "Hey, there is only amount x of item y left! Timestamp xxxxxxxx", and should be sent from the existing python code which uses a JSON-File as "Database" to track the items and their amounts.

I have looked into the matter, but found Microsoft's documentations to be a bit confusing, so I figured it might be better to ask here what the easiest way to tackle this looks like.

What is the best way to tackle this task? Would it make sense to make a bot, or is this not necessary, as there is a way to post a message through the API or something similar?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Meghana-MSFT I have been able to figure out how to do it. This code works perfectly well for sending a message over a webhook. If that's all you wanna to, this worked perfectly for me.

```
import requests 
headers = {} 
webhook_1 = "Webhook Nr.1" 
webhook_2 = "Webhook Nr.2" 
webhook_for_message = webhook_1 


def send_to_teams(webhook_for_message, message_to_send): 
  json_data = {
        'text': message_to_send,
    }

    response = requests.post(
        webhook_for_message,
        headers=headers,
        json=json_data,
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, it seems like a bot would be a good fit for your needs. Specifically, a notification bot in Microsoft Teams could be used to send proactive messages to users when the inventory of a certain item falls below a threshold.
Here's a high-level overview of how you could approach this:

1. Create a notification bot app: You can use the Microsoft Teams Toolkit to create a bot application. This bot will be responsible for sending notifications to the relevant users in Teams.
2. Integrate your Python web app with the bot: Your existing Python web app, which tracks the inventory, can trigger the bot to send a notification when the inventory of an item falls below a certain threshold. This can be done by making an HTTP POST request to the bot.
3. Format the notification message: The message that the bot sends can be formatted as per your needs. For example, it can be "Hey, there is only amount x of item y left! Timestamp xxxxxxxx".

You can find more information about creating a notification bot in Teams in the [Microsoft Teams platform documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/notification-bot-in-teams?tabs=ts1%2Cts2%2Cts3%2Cts4%2Cjsts%2Cts5#notification-bot-in-teams).

You can also use Graph API to send email - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http.

Please refer incoming webhooks as well - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Thanks for leading me into the right direction. I ended up converting the curl code to Python code in the following manner, as I really just wanted to send messages without interactions for now.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?